# How to create a sparse matrix with [-1,1] uniform distribution in julia

Tags: julia

I read [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Zbe.png) introduction to `sprandn` and tried to create a sparse matrix obeying [-1,1] uniform distribution.

```
using SparseArrays
using Distributions
sprandn(100,100,0.3,Uniform(-1,1))
```

But it failed. I apologize for not having pasted the error log. Here is an image of what the error says in [MethodError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc545.png).

So how can I generate a [-1,1] uniform distribution sparse matrix?

Comment: `sprandn` samples from the Normal distribution. You need to use `sprand` Even doing that, it still doesn't work for me, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

`sprandn` is for sampling from a standard normal.  However, there is a method of `sprand` that you can use:

```
sprand(m::Integer, n::Integer, density::AbstractFloat, rfn::Function)
```

The last argument is a function used internally for sampling the non-zero values, and you can use it like this:

```
D = Uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
rf(n) = rand(D, n)
sprand(100, 100, 0.3, rf)
```

If you want to specify the used RNG, this needs to be passed into `rf` as another argument in first position.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the documentation, because it actually says to use `sprandn` with a distribution. I also cannot see why `Uniform()` must be wrapped in a function. That seems _very_ strange, and not described in the docs (at a quick glance).

Comment: `sprandn` [internally](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/80516ca20297a67b996caa08c38786332379b6a5/stdlib/SparseArrays/src/sparsematrix.jl#L1494) just uses `sprand` with `randn` as random function. But yeah, the docs must be wrong, and strangely so: Base depending on Distributions would be unexpected to me.

Comment: I opened an issue on the documentation here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31283

Comment: I don't really think that Base is depending on Distributions, as such. `rand`/`sprand` etc. simply allow a distribution to be specified. That could come from Distributions or anywhere else.